# catch fire; catch on fire

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

> [1.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x4.asp?t=4103773&ID=660057754) Seventy percent of the man's body had been burned after the truck **caught fire**.  
>   [2.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x4.asp?t=4104131&ID=660255338) The house just **caught on fire**. 
>   (All are from COCA)

I’ve thought that ‘*on*’ gives the nuance of continuity. So the difference between 1 and 2 would be the property, is the thought. But is there really the difference? Or are there any other differences? Or there are no differences at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they mean exactly the same thing.

*Catch fire* is by far the more common idiom; *catch on fire* seems to be due to influence from *on fire*.

There also seems to be a regional difference; in the British National Corpus, the ratio of *caught on fire* to *caught fire* is 3:144, whereas in COCA, the ratio is 88:542. So whereas *caught on fire* sounds fairly normal to me (an American), albeit somewhat colloquial, I'm guessing that most British speakers would find it noticeably strange.

Comment: By the way, you might consider using square brackets to search the BYU corpora for all forms of a given word at the same time.  In COCA, we find [`[catch] on fire`](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33829275) (168 results) and [`[catch] fire`](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33829274) (936 results).  Clicking "compare BNC" from these results pages gives us 3 and 200 results respectively.